# Switch Alt and LWindows key in PC (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I have a Windows 7 keyboard that has Ctrl-LWindows-Alt bottom left.
Can I switch LWindows-Alt layout to Alt-LWindows?

---

Thanks for the answers!

I checked, downloaded the tools and tested very briefly. I must say that Will's answer is the best for me as I don't have to do anything but drag and drop. And as it just changes the registry, I expect no resource would be used. I remapped TAB and L-Windows key to Alt (meta) so that I can use Emacs with my PC like the one with my Mac.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use Remapkey.exe. It is available for free in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).

[image]

Comment: Nice. This would seem to be the more up-to-date version of the MKLC - I didn;t know this existed.

Comment: +1 - I'll remember this for the next keyboard remapping question that comes up!

Comment: Note: You have to right-click remapkey.exe and choose "Run as Administrator" for it to be able to write the results to the registry.

Answer (score 8):

As an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
LAlt::LWin
LWin::LAlt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). This allows you to create custom keyboard layouts, which are then installed and can be set as the system keyboard layout.

It'd be pretty easy to create a layout with the Alt and Windows keys switched, and this method has the advantage of residing much lower in the OS than a 3rd party tool or Hotkey program. This means that when you hit Alt, the OS *sees it as LWindows* (and of course vice versa). This is going to be more reliable than overriding the default behaviour of a system key, which AutoHotKey seems to offer.

Comment: Why'd this get an upvote?  MKLC (as of the current version 1.4) calls such special keys "unassignable," and then, of course, does not let you assign them.

Comment: Possibly because it worked when I posted it, more than 5 years ago.

Comment: fair enough, although it seems strange that they would have removed this functionality.

Comment: can you elaborate on how that is possible - since judging by this image of ms klc 1.4  it isn't showing the windows key  http://i.imgur.com/KtbcFvF.png

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [How to remap Right-Win and Right-Alt keyboard keys](https://superuser.com/a/1197884/516482) for information what `Remapkey.exe.` in [@WilliamHilsum's answer](https://superuser.com/a/188947/516482) does in the background (and what you easily can achieve with `.reg` files, the applying of which can be automated, too).