# How to remap Right-Win and Right-Alt keyboard keys

Tags: windows, windows-registry, keyboard-layout, keymap

... on a [Unicomp Ultra Classic Buckling Spring](https://www.pckeyboard.com/page/category/UltraClassic) keyboard in particular.

I recently bought one of these IBM Model M revivals. A great keyboard with one slight flaw: there are no *Power*, *Sleep*, *Wake* keys and a rather big flaw: they decided to swap the Right-Win and the Right-Alt keys so that it looks like:

<kbd>Space</kbd>    <kbd>[image]</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>[image]</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

With many years of using a different layout this is uncomfortable, of course.

I tried [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) 1.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812190509/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339), but it refuses to work properly on my Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit: it doesn't display the layout after *File* → *Load Existing Keyboard...*:

[image: Empty MSKLC]

See also [Any ideas why Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 refuses to work properly on my Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit?](https://superuser.com/q/1198160/516482).

Comment: just for your information: using the RemapKey-Tool from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools, you can remap the keys without manually altering the registry. I'm actually going to do that when my second Ultra Classic arrives (this new layout is so stupid...)

Comment: @MFH Thanks for the info. Though, I knew that. The real issue here is that I have to set/reset the Registry settings and reboot every time I want to switch to my laptop's internal keyboard and vice versa. With MSKLC I could switch the "language" and its assigned keyboard layout on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) 1.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812190509/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) fails to work properly you can use the following low-level solution that is derived from information on  (German) [WinFAQ](http://www.winfaq.de/faq_html/Content/tip1500/onlinefaq.php?h=tip1575.htm).

Create the following two `.reg` files with a text editor of your choice and execute them alternately to load the given keys/values into your Windows' Registry:

#### `HKLM^SYS^CCS^CTRL^Kbd_Layout^Scancode_Map#Swap_R-Win_R-Alt.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:\
  00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,\
  03,00,00,00,\
  38,e0,5c,e0,\
  5c,e0,38,e0,\
  00,00,00,00
```

#### `HKLM^SYS^CCS^CTRL^Kbd_Layout^Scancode_Map#Reset.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:\
  00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,\
  01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00
```

Note the reversed order of [LSB (least significant byte)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit#Least_significant_byte) and [MSB (most significant byte)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit#Other_uses) within the 2 bytes of a scancode, a.k.a. [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Note also the backslash character (`\`) for line continuation.

You have to restart Windows/reboot your machine for a change of mappings to take effect.

#### Technical Background Info

`Scancode Map` entry:

| Bytes | Size | Values | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 … 3 | 4 | `00 00 00 00` | Header: Version info, always all 0 |
| 4 … 7 | 4 | `00 00 00 00` | Header: Flags, always all 0 |
| 8 … 11 | 4 | `LM¹HM²00 00` | Header: `M`appings count (c) + 1 (for the trailer) in little-endian byte order, i.e. at least `01 00 00 00` |
| 12 … s | c × 4 | `LN¹HN²LO HO` | `N`ew / `O`ld scancodes in little-endian byte order (s = 11 + c × 4) |
| t … t+3 | 4 | `00 00 00 00` | Trailer (t = s + 1 = 12 + c × 4) |

¹ L ... low byte, [least significant byte (LSB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit#Least_significant_byte)
² H ... high byte, [most significant byte (MSB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit#Other_uses)

See the following pages/documents for scancodes:

- WinFAQ: [ScanCodes der Tasten](http://www.winfaq.de/faq_html/Content/tip1500/onlinefaq.php?h=tip1576.htm) (German; scancodes' byte order is already reversed there and such ready for entering into `.reg` files or directly into the Registry via Windows' Registry Editor)
- Andries Brouwer: [Keyboard scancodes](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html)
- Microsoft: [Windows Hardware Dev Center Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/download/dn550976%28v=vs.85%29):
- Input / HID Archive: [Keyboard Scan Code Specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc) (DOC)
- USB and 1394 Archive: [USB HID to PS/2 Scan Code Translation Table](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf) (PDF)

#### UPDATE

MSKBLC works with Windows' DPI Settings of 100 % only (see [Sam Arutuk's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1398929/516482) to my question [Any ideas why Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 refuses to work properly on my Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit?](https://superuser.com/q/1198160/516482)):

[image: MSKBLC...working with 100% DPI]

Apparently the <kbd>[image]</kbd> <kbd>[image]</kbd> keys can't be remapped.