# How to remap Fn to Ctrl on apple keyboard a1242?

Tags: windows, keyboard

How to remap <kbd>Fn</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on apple keyboard a1242?

<kbd>Fn</kbd> can be remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on new magic keyboards by using [magic utilities](https://magicutilities.net/magic-keyboard/features) for windows, but it doesn't support apple a1242 or a1243.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have a convenient way to modify the keymap without third party software.

This question [Remap right alt keys](https://superuser.com/questions/1197883/how-to-remap-right-win-and-right-alt-keyboard-keys) references some tools to do the job, and it also has how to manually modify the registry.

This standard format of the path to where to make the change if the software doesn't work for you. 
 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`