# Windows and Alt keys are reversed (among other problems)

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout

I've recently started using a Bluetooth keyboard (German layout (Deutsch (QWERTZ))) instead of my laptops keyboard (also German layout (Deutsch (QWERTZ))).

[image: Picture of my keyboard]

I noticed the following issues with the keyboard on a laptop running Windows 11:

- the keys marked as <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> respectively work as windows keys
- the key marked <kbd>Win</kbd> on the left side for all that I know works as <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
- the key marked <kbd>Win</kbd> on the right side works as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key for the symbols of the number row as well as for producing `~@€µ` (on `+qem` respectively) but not for producing `<>|` (on `yxc`)
- the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works for the <kbd>Fx</kbd> row, as well as on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, but not on the arrow keys, where it instead works as the <kbd>Win key.</kbd>
- the Ctrl key works as expected, for what I know.

When using my laptops keyboard while the Bluetooth keyboard is connected, the laptops keyboard works as expected, while the Bluetooth keyboard doesn't.

I would really appreciate help on how to make the Bluetooth keyboard work as expected, because I'm trying to work more ergonomically and would like to avoid buying another Bluetooth keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [ABKO TOS250](https://abkoglobal.com/product/tos250-wireless-keyboard/) keyboard has some system detection mechanisms that failed for whatever reason the first time you paired the keyboard on Windows and thus it applied a different layout more suitable for Mac devices. It could be a bug in the keyboard's firmware. Or perhaps this is some Chinese "copy paste" product, since the logo is missing, and they failed to code it properly.

A way to fix these kind of issues is to attempt to reconnect the device:

- disconnect/remove it in Windows Bluetooth settings
- reconnect with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (keybind to connect with Mac/Windows device) according to the device's [manual](https://manuals.plus/abko/tos250-multi-device-wireless-keyboard-manual)

Answer (score 2):

The work-around solution is to `re-map the keyboard`, which means re-assign the keys to what **you** want them to be. In general there are two methods:

First, a slightly more advanced solution where you can set individual keys to new functions or remap complex button combinations into simplified single-button presses.
You can use Microsoft's own *Powertoys*, to do this.

Go here:
https://www.lifewire.com/remap-keyboard-in-windows-10-5181178

And here:
https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/remap-your-keyboard

The **advantage** of this method is that you can assign multiple keystrokes to one key.
**Disadvantage** is that to use this you will need to install extra software which always has some risk. There is a chance the site you get it from might have altered or re-engineered it, virustotal.com kind of always find suspicious stuff from software you download from the big software sites

***Secondly***, a method which does key-for-key replacement by altering the registry directly. There's a program called *Sharp Keys*, which can write .reg files which will alter the registry. Specifically, the  Scancode Map key under the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout** 'branch' in the registry is altered

Because of that, a restart is needed for the change to take effect. https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-window

For example, you can make the Z key into a Y key and vice versa. Or disable the CAPS lock key or turn it into the `PrntScrn` key.

So, the **upside** of this method is that it's very clean, it doesn't require any 3rd party software, Sharp Keys in fact it gives you the option of writing a .reg file with which you can change that registry branch (Be sure to back that up first!)
The **downside** is that you can not put three keys into one, for example change *CapsLock* to *CtrlShftEsc*.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is the [ABKONCORE TOS250](https://abkoglobal.com/download_home/?vid=19) [Multi-Device keyboard](https://abkoglobal.com/product/tos250-wireless-keyboard/). Regardless of the model and brand, it's a keyboard for both macOS and Windows, and macOS has reversed keys compared to Windows. The <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key produces the same scan code as <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> key is the same as the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> on Windows, but <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> is on the right of <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>

So the keyboard is in macOS mode. In most multi-device keyboards likes this there should be some key or key combinations to switch the format back to Windows. Unfortunately this keyboard's [manual](https://manuals.plus/abko/tos250-multi-device-wireless-keyboard-manual) [page](https://usermanual.wiki/ABKO/TOS250) is quite silent on that. I suppose that is some <kbd>Fn</kbd> combinations

If all failed and you can't find the combo to switch mode then you can remap the keys

- [How to remap Right-Win and Right-Alt keyboard keys](https://superuser.com/q/1197883/241386)
- [Can I switch the alt and ctrl keys on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/1190329/241386)
- [How can I remap a keyboard key?](https://superuser.com/q/36920/241386)